# Blank out file while preserving the file's timestamp

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a Windows/DOS batch file I need to make an existing file zero bytes long. That's the easy part. However, I also need to preserve the timestamp (i.e., last modified time) of the file. Any ideas??

Comment: Not in a batch file; you're going to need an actual executable.  Why would you want to do this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The utime function sets the modification time for the file specified by filename.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wacf567.aspx

Comment: Thanks but I need to do this in a dos batch file. Not sure if that's possible.

Comment: Well, you could write a program that you call from a batch file.